# Code coverage is always unknown in GitLab

Tags: unit-testing, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to understand the GitLab Pipelines and after a few tries I was able to successfully automate my unit tests. Now I'm trying to add the code coverage badge into my project and/or readme file but it always seems to show `unknown`.

**Files:**

```
+ application
+ system
- unit-tests
  - tests
      UtilTest.php
    autoload.php
    phpunit
  .gitignore
  .gitlab-ci.yml
  .htaccess
  index.php
  readme.md
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
image: php:5.6

stages:
  - test

app:unit-tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - php ./unit-tests/phpunit --bootstrap ./unit-tests/autoload.php ./unit-tests/tests
  coverage: '/Code Coverage: \d+\.\d+/'
```

On the project's `Test coverage parsing` section I have this set up:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add console log?

Comment: @TalhaJunaid there are no errors on the console. It just says the tests were completed successfully. No mentions about code coverage. I was able to come up with a solution yesterday though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to fix this by using PHP 7.2 as the Docker image and installing `xdebug` on the `before_script` call.

**.gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
image: php:7.2

stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - pecl install xdebug
  - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

app:unit-tests:
  stage: test
  script:
  - php ./unit-tests/phpunit --bootstrap ./unit-tests/autoload.php ./unit-tests/tests --coverage-text --colors=never
  coverage: '/^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%/'
```

I had to use PHP 7.2 because when I tried running `pecl install xdebug` it said it requires PHP 7. Ideally I would like to use PHP 5.6 because that's what our current server has just so the tests are on similar versions but I'll leave it as it is for now.

I had to add `--coverage-text --colors=never` on the `script` call for it to output the numbers. Then on the `coverage` call I changed it to `'/^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%/'` which I also used under the `Test coverage parsing` section on the project settings.

And now the code coverage properly shows me my expected values.

Comment: `pecl install xdebug-2.5.5` should work with PHP 5.6

Comment: @SaschaFrinken out of curiosity, is there a way for me to only install the `xdebug` extension only once instead of doing it for every single time the pipeline is triggered?

Comment: Create an extra Gitlab project where you build a php-56 docker image that extends the default php56 image and install all the extra modules (pecl etc.) you need and publish it to the gitlab registry. Now you can use this image in your ci.

Comment: I created a gitlab project (https://gitlab.com/sfrinken/php-56-xdebug) to show what I mean. HTH

Comment: @SaschaFrinken I get this `The page could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.`. Is the project public?

Comment: Sorry, try again

Comment: @SaschaFrinken So I guess I need to set up **Registry** first. Anyways, I imported your project to our GitLab instance and used a shared runner. I'm getting these warnings/errors: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/mRFF2WUD)

Comment: Check your `config.toml` of your runner set `privileged=true`.